# Find point P on line BC equidistant to points A and O without calculation.

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry, plane-geometry, projection

Consider the following points $A(5,3,3)$ $ B (2,6,2)$ $ C(3,8,2)$ $O(0,0,0)$.
The problem asks to construct a point P on line BC that is equidistant to A and O using projections on a frontal and horizontal plane.
The problem should be easy to solve by calculation by taking a point P on line BC and then solving the equation PA=PO, but i have no idea how to solve this problem using no calculation.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution where you use only projections on plane xy and plane OAA' - the plane orthogonal to xy.

See the image, all the projections on xy plane are drawn red, and projections on OAA' are black

[image]

You start from the red A' and end on the P"'.

A' - projection of A on xy

S - mid point of OA

P' - projection of P on OAA'

P" - projection of P' on xy

P"' - projection of P on xy